# Package dependencies: Codeblocks

Tags: software-installation

So I downloaded the Codeblocks IDE in `tar.xz` format. I am fairly new to Linux and downloaded this format so I can install packages myself. I have extracted the archive to a folder and they are all `.deb` files. When I try to install, it complains of dependencies.

So what the heck am I to do now? Please I'll appreciate a terminal approach.

Comment: did you try sudo apt-get -f install 
This command solve dependency issues.

Comment: I already downloaded the package from source forge.com on another device.

Comment: what is your ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Codeblocks from Ubuntu repository. This will make your life easier by installing all the dependencies. So open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install -y Codeblocks
```

You may have to enable universe repository to install this. Read [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)